# How to write a new line in same .csv file each time script is ran?

Tags: python, csv

I have the below script to write to a **.csv** file - which works, but I am running the script on multiple files..

I am using the: `from csv import DictWriter`

**Currently it just write and updates the same line over and over again..** So my /`metrics.csv` only ever gets one row... How could I get this to update to a new row each time?

***/find_pending_records.py***

```
def get_excel_data(self):
    """Places excel data into pandas dataframe"""

 ...........

        with open("./logs/metrics.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            csv_writer = DictWriter(f, ['date', 'total', 'processed', 'skipped', 'total_zips', 'success_rate'])
            csv_writer.writeheader()

            currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
            success_rate = num_valid_records / total_records * 100
            csv_writer.writerow(dict(date=currentDT,
                                    total=total_records,
                                    processed=num_valid_records,
                                    skipped=num_invalid_records,
                                    success_rate=num_valid_records / total_records * 100))

        return self.clean_data_frame(excel_data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without even going too deep in to your code the problem is the following line

```
with open("./logs/metrics.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
```

That opens the file in `write` mode so you need to change the `w` to `a` so it opens the file in `append` mode instead.

Comment: Muy bien!! However, it write the head each time as well? How can I only get the header to write once?

Comment: that's because you specified that `newline=""` as opposed to `\n` for it to write on a new line, and every time you open the file you write the headers, you'll have to take the header writing logic out of the for loop so that it only happens once

Comment: this: 'with open("./logs/metrics.csv", "a", newline="\n") as f:'?

Comment: yes but you will still write the headers every time because that logic resides within the loop that is run every time you open a file. you will have to move that logic outside of the loop

Comment: Good enough; I'll figure that part out. Thanks!